# Can a SINGLE string command extract only the numbers?

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, oracle11g

EDITED:

I have strings like this: `C1,C4,C7-12,C15,C19` or `DS23, 28, 35, 39`. I need a string command if possible to extract only the characters in the numeral ASCII subset. So: `C1,C4,C7-12,C15,C19` would become only `147121519` abandoning all of the alpha chars, spaces, and punctuation. Likewise `DS23, 28, 35, 39` would become `23283539`.

My table:

```
 Part_Number  Ref_Location
 12345        C1, C4, C7-12, C15, C19
 AB354        DS1,5,19-37,46
 N-98DX       R1, R5-7, R75
```

My SQL:

SELECT Part_Number, SpecialStringFunction(Ref_Location,`0123456789`) from table;

Desired result

```
 12345        147121519
 AB354        15193746
 N-98DX       15775
```

I'm using Microsoft Access 2010 and connected to Oracle 11g

Comment: What variant of SQL? The [tag:sql] tag is for the standard language, but string manipulation facilities vary a lot between products. Please edit and add a suitable tag for your product.

Comment: Should be doable if your DBMS supports string replacement based on regular expressions.

Comment: so you need to extract and then normalize within the same query? it'd be way faster to extract in the query and then normalize application-side.

Comment: sql-server, PatIndex, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx

Comment: @Damien - Hey Damien, I'm using Microsoft Access 2010 and I'm linked to an Oracle 11g tablespace.

Comment: http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/06/varying-in-lists.html + use pass-through query, and just manipulate from oracle...it would require a module in Access

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to this to accomplish your task.

```
SELECT MAX (yy)
  FROM (    SELECT TO_NUMBER ( (REPLACE (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (x, ','), ',', '')))
                      AS yy
              FROM (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('C1,C4,C7-12,C15,C19',
                                              '[[:digit:]]',
                                              1,
                                              LEVEL)
                                  AS x, LEVEL AS y
                          FROM DUAL
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10)
        CONNECT BY PRIOR y = y - 1)
```

**If you are using Oracle 11g then you could very well make use of listagg function instead of the SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH.**